# reasonable amount of time to wait before following up query about incorrect pay?

Tags: salary

I joined a new company 7 months ago, as part of their offer my salary was to increase by £3000 after completing a 6 month probationary period.

After successfully completing this period my pay for last month didn't reflect the increase I was expecting. I contacted HR about this on Thursday but they were out of office until Monday, I got a response on Monday saying they would look into it and ask senior management and I sent them the offer letter I originally received from them that confirmed the pay rise.

I have heard nothing back since then, I don't understand why because this is a straight forward situation as far as I can tell. How long is a reasonable amount of time to wait to hear back before following up and how should i follow up in a polite but firm way.

Comment: Did you contact HR before going to your manager? I mean if your manager forgot to file some paperwork, that might make them look silly. Also I find if a manager is championing a cause, red tape doesn't disappear but it does get lessened.

Comment: You contacted HR on Thursday, they replied Monday that they will look into it, and you are asking on Tuesday how long you should wait? Depending on the company, even setting up a meeting with the boss within a day might be difficult. If your claim is correct, it should be corrected retroactively, so you shouldn't lose any money; worst case it'll just take another pay period before you get it.

Comment: I've been on that situation recently. Since you are fairly new to the company give them a week as @JoeStrazzere says, but if you don't get answers start being pushy and going in person. Sometimes HR just ignores you and you need to be a pain to get what it's in the contract. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would wait until the next pay period and go to your manager if it still is not corrected.

Comment: Why? Let's say someone else were to post an answer that says, as an example, "I would wait three days and go to your manager if it still is not corrected.". What makes either answer more or less correct?